# Teamwork API authorisation without giving away full Teamwork access

Tags: api, authorization, teamwork-projects

I'm using Teamwork as a project management tool in my team. It is a great tool, but it ridiculously lacks some important functionality. For example, their reporting facility sucks.

Though, they have API using which I can build reports myself. API key is specific to the user, so using any given API key you get access of the owner of the key.

So, if I give my API key, anyones who has it, gets access to all infromation in Teamwork (including information under NDA). So giving my API is not an option.

Making an app where I need to put my API key manually is not an option too, as developer still can get access to this key (by simply recording all inputted keys).

So my question is: is there some way to make authorisation like the one facebook has for other sites for services where such kind of authorisation is not implemented?